# Maclaurin Series Help

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

My problem is to numerically approximate the series `(1 - Cos[x])/x` over the interval `[0,1]`.

I typed it into Mathematica as so:

```
Series[(1 - Cos[x])/x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

and I got in return

```
x/2 + O[x]^2
```

My question is what does that final `O[x]^2` mean, and also if I am solving what is asked for. Thanks!

Comment: O[x]^2 means roughly the "..." you sometimes see written at the end of series in math texts. It means there is "some other stuff that is about the same magnitude as x times a constant and then all that stuff is squared. If you change your  {x, 0, 1} to  {x, 0, 8} then you can see more terms of the series and a much smaller "stuff" at the end.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation for

```
Series
```

Then you can see that

```
Series[f,{x,Subscript[x, 0],n}] generates a power series
expansion for f about the point x=Subscript[x, 0] to order (x-Subscript[x, 0])^n
```

So if you want more terms, then simply change n to something else. Like 5, for example.

```
In[6]:= Series[(1 - Cos[x])/x, {x, 0, 5}]

x/2-x^3/24+x^5/720+O(x^6)
```

n gives you the highest term. If you look at the formula for the MacLaurin series then you know that it is an infinite series, so in general when you look at the first n terms you then have infinitely many more terms which are polynomials of order higher than n. This would be denoted as O[x^n] in Mathematica. Hope this helps.

In general the documentation is a great place to look first. Good luck!